# Why doesn't the LSTM model improve the time-series forecasting significantly with respect to the MLP model?

Tags: deep-learning, long-short-term-memory, time-series, multilayer-perceptrons, forecasting

I have recently started learning time series forecasting. I have a dataset of the weekly payment history of 10k clients over 1 year, and I want to predict the future 5 payments for a test set of 1k clients.

From what I have tried, I've found that using LSTMs instead of a simple MLP doesn't improve the prediction as much as I anticipated.
My understanding is that LSTMs captures the relations between time steps, whereas simple MLPs treat each time step as a separated feature (doesn't take succession into consideration).

So, my question is: why doesn't the LSTM model improve the forecasting significantly? What are the best models for such a task, given that the time series are short (maximum sequence's length = 52)?

Comment: I would suggest using statistical methods like ARIMA even before machine learning.

Comment: I have tried VARMA, since here I have multiple Time Series. But, the RMSE was very high.

Answer (score 1):

RNNs are known to be superior to MLP in case of sequential data, like yours. But complex models like LSTM and GRU require a lot of data to achieve their potential. I don't know about your data but you can try to validate your architecture, approach and overall setting using a different, known time-series benchmark data.
Maybe something is wrong with architecture, loss function, data, etc...
So trying a different but known benchmark data can give you an idea about why you are unable to produce superior results with LSTM.